# How to get list elements in Velocity using foreach loop to display as a table

Tags: list, foreach, velocity

I have a list which i am getting from database.I have 6 elements in the list

```
 List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add("No Connection");
 list.add("sep 24 ,2009");
 list.add("no issues are there");
 list.add("dec 30,2012");
 list.add("no meter");
 list.add("april 12,2013");


map.put("list",list);
```

I am using Velocity template. In that i am using foreach loop to get the list items.I have to display in the table with two cells in the first cell three elements in the even indexes should display and in second cell odd indexes should display.How can do that.

```
#foreach($mylist in $list)
    <td>even indexed list elements in my list</td>
    <td align="center">odd indexed elements in the list.</td>
    #end
```

**Update:**

I tried like this but it doesn't work.Is this correct way of getting indexes in velocity.

```
#set ($counter = 0)
#foreach ($i in $descList)
    #set ($counter = $counter + 1)
    #if ( $couter % 2 == 0)
        <td>$descList[$i]</td>
        <td align="center"></td>
    #else
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">$descList[$i+1]</td>
    #end
#end
```

I am getting following error.

07:53:31,952 ERROR VelocityEngine:43 - Left side ($couter) of modulus operation has null value. Operation not possible. /emailtemplates/diis_nem_issues_email.vm [line 47, column 20]

07:53:31,953 ERROR VelocityEngine:43 - Left side ( 2 ) of '==' operation has null value. If a reference, it may not be in the context. Operation not possible. /emailtemplates/diis_nem_issues_email.vm [line 47, column 25]

Comment: It works - you simply had a typo: couter instead of counter -.-'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using hashtable in my application instead of List in my application

```
#foreach( $key in $hashtab.keySet() )
 <tr><td>$key</td><td align="center">$hashtab.get($key)</td></tr>
#end
```

and in my java class i have like this

```
HashTable<String,Date> hashtab=new HashTable<String,Date>();
hashtab.put(key,value);
```

Thanks guys for your Ideas.

Comment: How/why did using HashTable solve the issue?  Was it a concurrency problem?  I'm having something similar happen where elements within lists intermittently are not resolving within the VelocityEngine.

Comment: I used Hash Table because I have to display some associated data in tabular format like created by , created date. So Once I get those values from my code I will put those two values in the Map and send to Velocity template to extract Key and values of the map. Basically if fits exactly my requirement.What is the exact issue you are having?

Comment: I'm doing something similar where I have values I need Velocity to populate from a Map (Hashmap implementation).  Once in awhile (maybe 1 out of 200-300 values) a random value will resolve as null.  When I check the DB, there's nothing missing/different about the records being fed into the Velocity template.  I wasn't sure if maybe the Velocity engine has an issue with concurrency when a Map is provided, so I've switched to using ConcurrentHashMap.  I'm hopeful this resolves my issue (difficult to test, as this happens only in the production environment).

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this snippet that works for me:

```
#set( $count = 1 )
<p>User details:</p>
<table>
    #foreach( $user in $users)
        <tr>
            <td>$count</td>
            <td>$user.username</td>
            <td>$user.age</td>
        </tr>
        #set( $count = $count + 1 )
    #end
</table>
```

where '$users' is a List that I'm setting in java, like this:

```
List<User> users = ...
params.put("users", users);
```

I found these solution here: http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com.ar/2010/03/velocity-templates-for-email.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a typo: `couter` instead of `counter`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember you could do something like this:

```
#set ($counter = 0)
#foreach ($mylist in $list)
    #set ($counter = $counter + 1)
    #if ( $couter % 2 == 0)
        <td>even indexed result</td>
        <td align="center"></td>
    #else
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">odd index result</td>
    #end
#end
```

Comment: Yeah, but you don't need a counter.  Velocity comes with one:  Just use $foreach.index instead of $counter

Comment: Out of curiosity don't we need to do "count++"? and can you please show me how to get the even and odd indexes into those td's. I am not much fimilar with velocity template language.

Answer (score 0):

There is an small mistake in the code, as follows:

```
if ( $**couter** % 2 == 0)

**couter** ->>>> **counter**
```